# Validation on Databoud DataGridView per Column

Tags: c#

So I have a DataGridView which is used to display a list of custom models.
Here is some sample code for a model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetValidationErrors()
    {
        if (Value1 > 100 || Value1 <= 0)
            yield return "Value1 can only be between 1 and 100 (inclusive)";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Value2))
            yield return "Value2 can not be empty";
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get { return GetValidationErrors().Count() == 0; }
    }

    public int Value1
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Value2
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Now let's say I was Binding a list (or IEnumerable) of these models like so

```
List<TestModel> list = Helpers.GetListOfTestModels();
dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

(We can assume that the list return is valid, or else it wouldn't be stored).

Now on the `RowValidating` event on the DataGridView, I can validate the entire row by accessing the `IsValid` property and set a `Rows[].ErrorText`, like so:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    var item = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as TestModel;
    if (item == null)
        return;

    if(!item.IsValid)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "Failed Validation"; // Or use GetValidationErrors and concat them, but to be simple I've left that out
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Now, what I really want to do (without copying and pasting code all over the place), is validate each Property and set the `Rows[].Cells[].ErrorText` Property (this will show errors per cell, instead of the entire row).

How should I go about this?

Maybe something with Custom Attributes, then reflection to get the property name and access the cell that way?

Hopefully this all makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!

Have a abstract attribute like so:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public abstract class ValidationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public abstract void Validate(object value, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ref IList<string> errors);
}
```

and an implementation like so:

```
public class ValidStringAttribute  : ValidationAttribute
{
    #region Overrides of ValidationAttribute

    public override void Validate(object value, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ref IList<string> errors)
    {
        var v = propertyInfo.GetValue(value, null);

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(v as string))
        {
            errors.Add(string.format("`{0}` cannot be null or empty",propertyInfo.Name);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then Modify the `Value2` Property like so:

```
[ValidString]
public string Value2
{ 
   get; set;
}
```

and in either the `RowValidating` or `CellValidating` Events do something like this:

```
if(!item.IsValid)
{
    foreach(var propertyInfo in item.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        IList<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (ValidationAttribute attribute in propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute),true))
        {
            attribute.Validate(item,propertyInfo,ref list);
        }

        if(list.Count > 0)
        {
            // make sure it's not ignored
            var browsable = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (BrowsableAttribute), true);
            if(browsable.Count() == 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[propertyInfo.Name].ErrorText = list[0];
            }
        }
    }

    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

and bam errors per property, with databinding!

Comment: +1 You should look into the Enterprise Library - the Validation Block does stuff similar to this...

Comment: The stink thing is, this is a one off application which will be replaced in the next 6 months!! But I shall have a look, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you perhaps make use of the `CellValidating` event?  This event fires similarly to the `RowValidating` except it occurs when you tab out of the cell.

Alternatively, if your row represents a Business Object, then you can expose a `Validate` method that will perform validation over the properties and return an `Errors` array of properties  that have failed validation with a provided error message.  It does not automagically link to the UI, but it keeps validation in the object itself rather than the UI.